# Will a suitcase with a broken handle be accepted as checked in luggage?

Tags: luggage, regulations

I have an American Tourister spinner (luggage suitcase), which can only be checked in due to its size. Unfortunately, my expandable handle got damaged while it was expanded, and it can no longer fold so that it could be checked in. It's way past its warranty, as it's now something like fifteen years old, but I still really love it (as it has sentimental value to me).

Will this be acceptable for check in, or do I now need to get a new suitcase?

We're on holiday abroad and will be flying home soon.

Comment: The handle is stuck in the extended position?  I bet they won't take it like that, but have you considered trying to cut the handle off?

Comment: @mark mayo: You can have a look at it here: http://imgur.com/czXCEDy . I pulled out the textile part so that I could have a look at the mechanism and try to fix it, but it doesn't look like there's much I can do to get it closed.

Comment: @nate: I don't think that would be acceptable either, nor do I have a saw, or any other tools.

Comment: Well, a saw might be cheaper than a new suitcase (or you might manage to borrow one somewhere).  Anyway, even if you are allowed to check it, I think it is very likely that the handle will break off in transit.

Comment: Are you worried they'll reject it because it's too long, or because they're afraid of being sued for "damaging" the handle?

Comment: You should be able to get the handle off with just an inexpensive screwdriver (or try to borrow one). I had one where the telescoping tubes got bent and it wouldn't close- it was still possible to force it down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/can-a-slightly-damaged-suitcase-be-used-as-checked-luggage/90391#90391

Comment: Also, as I note in my answer to the linked question, this happened to me and everything went fine.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely they can accept that. It may even exceed the dimensions allowed in which is it is pretty much an automatic *not acceptable*. Otherwise some airlines may let it in. The last time that I checked in a cracked suitcase that was held by ducktape, the airline put a fragile sticker on it and another one that I had to sign a waiver saying some like *Improperly packed contents, airline not responsible*.

Your best bet is to remove the handle mechanism. Try to unscrew parts until it separates completely. Sometimes putting it back together after will make it slide back. Even if they do let  your check it in, it is unlikely that the suitcase will come out intact. Even good condition and really sturdy suitcase get damaged and its usually the wheels or handles that break first.

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend on the airline. Most airlines have baggage dimension limits, even for checked luggage. You'll need to look on their website.

Alternatively, you [could try to fix it yourself](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/150416/The+handle+on+my+Freewheeler+luggage+won%27t+retract%3B+what+do+I+do) if you have time and some tools, or worse case, take out the screws from the inside when you get to the airport, so that you can actually remove the handle, and place it in your bag.

Then when you get to the destination, reattach it and carry on as you were.